# How can I use a quoted search on a Google Alert?

Tags: google-alerts

Lately my Google Alerts have been turning up less relevant results, and I realize that they seem to have stopped search for the phrase I entered and have started just giving results that include each individual word (which is obviously less useful).

When I go to "Manage your alerts", any quotes I put in the search box are removed when it loses focus.

Has anyone else noticed this loss of functionality? Are there better services that might provide what I need?

Comment: I just tried to setup a new one and it worked. I then edited one of the ones I had saved and when it lost focus the quotes stayed around. What browser are you running and have you tried disabling any plugins that might interfere?